# Extracting Ruby string within a pattern within a scan or regex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby 2.0. I've currently got a string of:

```
str = "bar [baz] foo [with] another [one]"

str.scan(/\[.*\]/)
```

The output is:

```
["[baz] foo [with] another [one]"]
```

When I would expect it more like:

```
["[baz]","[with]","[one]"]
```

So I basically need to put everything between "[]" into an array. Can someone please show me what I'm missing out?

Comment: `str.scan(/\[.*?\]/) #=> ["[baz]", "[with]", "[one]"]`

Answer (score 4):

Your `.*` is greedy, so it doesn't stop until the final bracket.

You need to use a lazy quantifier `.*?` or only catch non-brackets: `[^\]]*`

Answer (score 2):

Regexs are greedy by default so your regex grabbing everything from the first [ to the last ]. Make it non-greedy like so:

```
str.scan(/\[.*?\]/)
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly thanks - same conclusion as Brian's answer